# Firebase Cloud Function Auth Trigger not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Express in my Cloud Function with multiple routes, and I'm trying to add in a function that when triggered, will pull the users Gravitar and add it to their user object.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot get the onCreate function to fire, and I suspect it's to do with how I'm attempting to export it.

My index.js looks like the following:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const usersApi = require("./api/users")
const paymentsApi = require("./api/payments")
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

const checkHeader = async(req, res, next) => {
  if(req.headers.authorization) {
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authorization)
    .then(token => {
      req.uid = token.uid;
      req.email = token.email;
      req.stripeID = token.stripeID || null;
      return next();
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return next(e.errorInfo.code)
    })
  } else {
      return next('No token found');
  }
}

app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(checkHeader);

app.disable("x-powered-by");

app.use("/users", usersApi)
app.use("/payments", paymentsApi)


const setupUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  console.log("onCreate")
  console.log(user)
})

module.exports = {
  api: functions.https.onRequest(app),
  setupUser
}
```

The api endpoint works fine, however I can't get the onCreate function to trigger when a user is created.

Comment: The code for `functions.auth.user().onCreate(` looks fine at first glance. How are you triggering it?

Comment: It automatically triggered when a user is added to Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Comment: I know. So what I'd like to know is how you're adding a user. :-)

Comment: Ah I figured it out.  Triggers don't work locally, they only work when the functions are hosted :(

Comment: Ah, for sure. There's no way to invoke your local emulator for background triggers. That would require all kinds of complex setup with reverse proxies. The only way to test these triggers is by explicitly invoking them in the emulator. See the docs for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_storage_auth_and_crashlytics_functions